# Do I need a Flash Media Server for a 1-1 chat

Tags: php, ajax, flash, chat

I am developing a new php based website and want to include a 1-1 chat functionality within it. 
Am currently looking at the below 2 options
1. Based on Flash
2. Based on PHP/Ajax

Need help with the following questions.
1. Will I really need a Flash Media server for this requirement? What advantages will an FMS give me over PHP/Ajax
2. Comparing between php/ajax and FMS, will the latter reduce my bandwidth usage?

Any other points I should be aware of before taking this decision?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an FMS for this, you can easily use Cirrus. (Adobes' RTMFP)
Have a look here: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

Or here's a tutorial on how to build a simple chat: http://www.flashrealtime.com/simple-chat-p2p-netgroup-rtmfp/

That is if you would still want to go the flash way though.

Comment: would you suggest going the flash way or do you think the simple php/ajax should suffice, considering the user base (concurrent) will not be more than 50